# How to split a line of code into multiple lines?

Tags: python, split, newline

I had to write a program to calculate Pi with 3 different algorithms.
I use the Chudnovsky Formula as my 3rd algorithm and it's a oneliner.
For readability my teacher asked if I could split it into multiple lines.

Code looks like this:

```
iteration_sum += ((-1)**k)*(Decimal((factorial(6*k)))/(Decimal((factorial(k)**3))*Decimal((factorial(3*k))))*(13591409+545140134*k)/(640320**(3*k)))
```

It would be great if I could split it after ...)))/(Decimal((...

Thanks for your help in advance.

Steve

Comment: Just separate the calculation into several steps. And don't afraid of adding extra variables when essential and adds readability.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to follow python [PEP 0008 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

More specifically [Maximum Line Length](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)

> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters.

Take some time reading it and get yourself familiar with it. For example:

```
with open('/path/to/some/file/you/want/to/read') as file_1, \
     open('/path/to/some/file/being/written', 'w') as file_2:
    file_2.write(file_1.read())
```

Note the `\` after a comma indicating a continuation on the next line.

With your example it comes down to preference, but it's best to do it after an operator:

```
iteration_sum += ((-1)**k)*(Decimal((factorial(6*k)))/
                            (Decimal((factorial(k)**3))*Decimal((factorial(3*k))))*
                            (13591409+545140134*k)/(640320**(3*k)))
```

The additional indentation indicate that they fall after the `((-1)**k)*(` for readability.

Comment: Would this approach be preferable to`with open('read') as file_1:`<new line and indent>`with open('written', 'w') as file_2:`?

Answer (score 6):

You may find your answer here. http://code.runnable.com/UqBbr4-VwoAMAAUN/how-to-write-multiline-statements-in-python

break your code line into several lines and put the \ at the end of each line.

```
print "this statement " + \
"goes " + \
"beyond " + \
"one " + \
"line " + \
"but gets printed as a single line"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use \ to split a long line of code in Python.
i.e:

```
result = 1 + 1\
 + 2 * 5\
 - 3.14 * 25
```

Comment: Although accurate, this is awkward and (in this case) unnecessary, not to mention discouraged by the style guide.

Comment: Yeah, your right. But it works. :) May Guido van Rossum forgive me, where ever he is right now :/

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Also, if you're splitting a large computation up into multiple lines, you can take the opportunity to name the more prominent "chunks", either with local variables or separate functions.  It can also clarify the order of operations in a complex expression:  `return _available(x, y) / _required(x, y)` highlights that the return value is a ratio better than any combination of added parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

besides PEP008, which is the Python truth in these matters, you can use the fact of being within a parenthesis to add newlines without requiring \.  In fact, this is the mechanism the accepted answer is using.

```
def foo():
    return (1 + 2 ) / (5 + 6 + 7 - 0.5)
```

Note the code below is not PEP008-compliant wrt to indents, just addresses line 
splits.

```
def foo2():

    #explicit new line with \
    #after you open a parenthesis ( you can add newlines implicitly until )
    return (1 + 2 ) \
        / (5 
        + 6 
        + 7 
        - 0.5)

print foo()
print foo2()


0.171428571429
0.171428571429
```

You commonly see this in options or dictionaries:

```
my_opt = dict(
    choice1=1,
    choice2=2,
    choice3=3,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually split right before the next argument. In your case it would look like this:

```
iteration_sum += ((-1)**k)*(Decimal((factorial(6*k)))/
                        (Decimal((factorial(k)**3))*Decimal((factorial(3*k))))*
                        (13591409+545140134*k)/(640320**(3*k)))
```

I hope that helps.